# Why this code does not throw classcast exception?

Tags: java

```
Object o=new int[]{1,2,3}; 
int[] array=(int[]) o; 
for(int a:array){
  //print the values
}
```

-Why dont i get a classcast exception here while iterating through the array given  that array extends Object class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in java *even arrays* are *Objects*. . If you print `array instanceof Object` , it returns true.

Next, you are creating an *array* and using an *Objects* reference. Since the final instance is an *array*, you will not get any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Object is the Super Class for all the Classes in Java. Every Class Extends Object Implcitly. So, instances of any class can be cast into Object type.

Answer (score 0):

Because `o` itself **is** array of `int[]`-array type. If it would be, for example, `o = new long[] {...}` - in this case, yes, it will throw an exception.